# C# Passing params to another view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a set up where a Company can have none or one or many clients. So there is no strict relationship between the Client table and the Company table. I have created a Search view where all companies are populated. Then using a button a client can be attached to the company. I thought using an `ActionLink` I would be able to achieve this, so my Search (view) has,

```
@Html.ActionLink("Book", "Book", new { id = a.CompanyId })
```

Where the Model is looped over to get all the company list. Now when I click the link, it populates the Address with the right params, `Companies/Book/1` the ID I am playing with is 1. Which is correct, however the View I am landing at is a new Customer Model.

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = true)]
    public long CompanyId { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Customer Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* required")]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address Line 1")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* required")]
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Postcode")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* required")]
    public string Postcode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"\d*", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid phone number")]
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
}
```

Even though I am able to see the ID being passed (using FireBug) is 1, somehow when I click the button to submit the view to the controller I get a 0. Why would this be? Could anyone help me?

**EDIT - 1**

This is the controller.

```
    public ActionResult Book()
    {
        return View(new CustomerModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveCustomer(CustomerModel model)
    {
        _companyService.SaveCustomer(model);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I have tried using the `CompanyId` instead of id, it came up with another error.

> Before submitting the Form, Address bar has : http://localhost:53294/Companies/Book?CompanyId=1
>
> After submitting the Form, Address Bar has : http://localhost:53294/Companies/SaveCustomer
>
> > The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Customer_dbo.Company_CompanyId". The conflict occurred in database "BoilerServicing", table "dbo.Company", column 'CompanyId'.
> >     The statement has been terminated.

The save method by itself,

```
    public void SaveCustomer(CustomerModel customer)
    {
        using (var db = new BoilerServicingDbContext())
        {
            Customer entity;
            if (customer.CustomerId > 0)
            {
                entity = db.Customers.First(x => x.Id == customer.CustomerId);
            }
            else
            {
                entity = new Customer();
                db.Customers.Add(entity);
            }

            entity.Name = customer.CustomerName;
            entity.TelephoneNumber = customer.PhoneNo;
            entity.AddressLine1 = customer.AddressLine1;
            entity.PostCode = customer.Postcode;
            entity.CompanyId = customer.CompanyId;

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your controller method?

Comment: same question here ? #PaulFrancis

Comment: @dotnetom, I have finished work now, will update the post in a few mins when I get home. I did try using companyId, but will give that another go.

Comment: @Rughaani, not sure what that meant.

Comment: what is your primary key name?

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Book", "Book", new { companyId = a.CompanyId },new{}) ,can you try this.

Comment: @Rughaani - Id is the primary key name in the table.

Comment: and what is companyId ?

Comment: Will surely give that a go, when I get home. Thank you !

Comment: your welcom  #PaulFrancis

Comment: @dotnetom, sorry it still coming up with the same problem.

Comment: @Rughaani, tried your method too. Still troubles. :( Sorry if I am making little or no sense. I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after trying so many ways, I have come to this. I changed the Action method on the controller.

```
    public ActionResult Book(long id)
    {
        return View(new CustomerModel
        {
            CompanyId = id
        });
    }
```

This seems to have passed in the CompanyId I am passing into the Book view. Took me a while, but I got there. Thanks for all your help !